# Direct download link for files using box api

Tags: box-api

We want to get a direct download link for a file that expires after some time, is there any end point for this in v2 api.

Dropbox has a media API which does it good enough. https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#media

We checked the docs and found that we can share a file and get a download link, but that will change the properties of a file and moreover that link works only with premium users.

--
Anurag

Answer (score 0):

The sharing link available through Box that you've found is pretty close to your requirements.  It is still possible to get a sharing link for non-premium users, just the link will be point to a download page instead of as a direct download link.

Do your needs require that it not have an intermediary step like that?

Comment: Yes, we don't want to have an intermediary step to download a file since it gives a bad user experience.